UNION ALL between tables with ALMOST identical fields
i'm in dire need of help
i've been agonizing over how to solve the following conundrum:
i have two tables, table1 and table2, with almost identical tracks and an immense number of fields, and i have the following query i'm supposed to fix:
SELECT *
FROM Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM Table2

table1 has an extra column, which we'll call ColumnX,
so this is the solution i thought of:
SELECT *
FROM Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT *, NULL AS DummyX
FROM Table2

but apparently i'm not allowed to do that due to inserting a bunch of NULL values and an empty column in the DB.
i'm also not allowed to execute CRUD operations.
i've been thinking of using EXCEPT/MINUS to remove ColumnX during the UNION ALL process and inserting it then afterwards but i don't think that's possible.
Please help?

What do you mean "i'm not allowed to do that due to inserting a bunch of NULL values and an empty column in the DB"? You are inserting nothing with this statement, it's merely a select statement. At any rate, if you don't need columnX then just write out the SELECT with ALL of the columns listed except ColumnX. It feels like you are tying yourself in knots with that *.

A [mre] here would be extremely helpful - we obviously don't need the real list of columns, but e.g. you could create one table with 3 columns, one with 2, and show us what output you're trying to achieve. You could then include the approaches you've thought of but are "not allowed", so that we can understand the actual problem.

that's the thing, the DB is extremely complex and i dont have a full list of all the *fields of the table, or rather supposedly i do, in practice im not sure. i know that merely being a select it would work without polluting the db but when i asked if that was the solution i was told i couldnt do that, i feel like my leg is being throughoutly pulled

Agree with @JNevill ...list out all columns instead of using SELECT *, then add the dummy column as you are doing in your first attempt.

Why not build a CTE if your RDBMS system allows it or use a temp table/derive table to transform table 1 to remove column X and then union?

In general, I agree with JNevill that the most likely answer is "don't use SELECT *". I make it a rule to never use SELECT * in any permanent code, because it makes the query extremely fragile to later schema changes. You'll need to give a bit more context to rationalise a query where you don't even know what columns will be returned.

Surely you can list out the columns in Table1 and Table2 if you can SELECT from them with a *. It may be arduous, but sometimes SQL is just like that, where you can write out SELECT field1, field2, field3, ... field973 FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT field1, field2, field3, ... field973 FROM table2 and be done with it.

that makes perfect sense, problem is i can't even run the script on the db cuz i dont have the accesses to it yet, like i'm going blind. fucking sucks, it does.
